# HTTP Public Key Pinning in Azure throws malformed key error

Tags: azure, public-key

Has anyone had any luck configuring HTTP Public Key Pinning in Azure by updating the web.config? I receive errors about a malformed key but can't pin down where the syntax error is.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
        <add name="Public-Key-Pins" value="pin-sha256='AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA='; pin-sha256='AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA='; max-age=10; includeSubdomains;" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Can't see an immediate problem with the code. Have you tried to add the header directly via RemoteIIS manager -> Response Headers? Also, in the portal.azure.com site (or older management site), you can add the ssl certificates there. Not sure if that does the same thing...but appears to upload the cert and generate the fingerprint for it.